# Again = 'back, opposite direction'

Tags: early-modern-english

In the OED, archaic *again*, under def. 1a, is 'In the opposite direction; back.' The last example given there is from John Bunyan, with "turn again": "Come then, Neighbour Pliable, let us turn **again**, and go home."

But in def. 1b, there are a few quotes with "turn again", from the same 1612 source (def. 1b: "Back to or towards the point of starting; all the way back; = back adv. 5. Frequently with verbs of motion, such as bring, come, go, turn, wend. Now archaic (in continued use of the expressions illustrated in quots. 1611, 1612) and Scottish (north-eastern)."):

1612   R. Johnson Crowne-Garland Goulden Roses sig. Bvv
"London bells sweetly rung... Euermore sounding so, turne againe Whittington: For thou in time shalt grow, Lord Maior of London."

1846  C. Dickens Dombey & Son (1848) iv. 32
"Turn again Whittington, Lord Mayor of London, and when you are old you will never depart from it."

1983   V. E. Neuburg Pop. Press Compan. to Pop. Lit. 81/1
"He was inspired by hearing Bow bells ring out a peal which seemed to say: Turn again Whittington, Lord Mayor of London."

So, I'm wondering why the Bunyan quote isn't in 1b, and if it is properly in 1a, then how is it different from the "turn again" 1b example(s)?

Comment: You don't say what Definition 1b is (we don't all have access to the OED!), but before I got to your second paragraph I was already thinking of the traditional rhyme "Turn again, Whittington."

Comment: ... Yes, Kate – that quote has (till now) always had me merely guessing that the 'again' was merely emphatic, 'turn again' meaning 'reverse your first decision, to flee' (and 'turn' at the same time meaning 'turn back').

Comment: The association of 'again' with return as well as repetition is still around today.  Most children and their parent know that the grand old Duke of York marched his ten thousand men to the top of the hill and then "matched them down again".  'Back' and 'again' are kindred words.  The prefix 're' in Latin and English can mean either:  'repeat', 'return' 'relent' ''repaint'...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the detail @KateBunting has noted is missing from your question. Also, you appear to be asking a separate, independent question about the KJB usage, and it's probably much too broad (are you asking us to check **every** use of *again* against the 1a definition?). Each of these issues is grounds for your question to be closed. I recommend you delete the second part of your question, and provide the 1b definition. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Comment: Does anyone know whether it is a mistake to place the Bunyan quote under def. 1a rather than def. 1b?

Comment: @Tuffy Doesn't "again" in The Grand Old Duke of York mean "once more"? If it weren't for the rhyme and metre of the verse we could say "...and marched them down once more". This actually means "to return them to where they started". I know that's another way of saying the same thing but it does indicate that "again" is not the only way to express the  concept.

Comment: @BoldBen But you couldn't say "he led them back for a second time."

Comment: @Tuffy You could but, to be fair, the meaning would be different